# How to evaluate external addresses with virtual regexp match in Postfix?

Tags: postfix, regex

I have the following situation. I want some more specific and some more generic virtual recipients. Assume, I have a user abc and a user john.
If I receive an email for abc@mydomain, I want to forward it to `john@external.com`. For user John, I want to provide multiple virtual email adresses, such that all emails that start with `/^john/` are forwarded to `johndoe@external.com`.

Now, in main.cf, I have:

```
virtual_alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual, regexp:/etc/postfix/virtual-regexp
```

virtual looks like this:

```
abc john@external.com
```

virtual-regexp looks like this:

```
/^john/ johndoe@external.com
```

If I now send an email to abc@mydomain, the mail is forwarded to `johndoe@external.com`. I assume this is because john@external.com is evaluated once more and matched with `/^john/`. How can I make the email being forwarded to `john@external.com`?

Answer (score 0):

I just found out, the virtual aliasing is recursive. So, the solution to my problem is to prepend

```
/^john@external.com$/ john@external.com
```

to the virtual-regexp file